# Is there anyway to stop implicity wait during try/except?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a selenium script that automates signing up on a website. During the process, I have driver.implicity_wait(60) BUT there is a segment of code where I have a try/except statement where it tries to click something but if it can't be found, it continues. The issue is that if the element isn't there to be clicked, it waits 60 seconds before doing the except part of code. Is there anyway I can have it not wait the 60 seconds before doing the except part? Here is my code:

```
if PROXYSTATUS==False:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[title='中国大陆']").click()
else:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[title='中国大陆']").click()
    except:
        pass
```

In other words if a proxy is used, a pop up will occasionally display, but sometimes it won't. That's why I need the try/except.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_page_load_timeout`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) to change the default timeout to a lower value that suits you.

You will still need to wait for some amount of time, otherwise you might simply never click on the element you are looking for, because your script will be faster than the page load.

Answer (score 0):

In the try block u can lower the timeout say 10 by using driver.implicity_wait(10) or even to 0. Place this before the find element statement in the try block. Add a finally block and set this back to 60 driver.implicity_wait(60).